# how to calculate an agreement value in a vote between multiple people?

Tags: agreement-statistics

I am not at all good with statistics which also doesn't help me looking for a proper answer.
I am trying to calculate an agreement value in a vote between multiple people. And people can vote in numbers (1, 2, 3, 5, etc).
What would be a nice way to have like a percentage of agreement in each voting round?

lets say i have something like this

```
 votesRound1 = { one: 4, two: 2, three: 1, five: 0}
 votesRound2 = { one: 7, two: 0, three: 0, five: 0}
```

then I would like to know based on that, how can I calculate the agreement scale.

So for votesRound2 I would expect the agreement to be 100%. But for the votesA I have no idea how to calculate, although I would expect something larger, since more than half the group voted on the same answer. I am just not at all familiar with a lot of stats concepts, so I don't know where to search for that answer.

*Why I am asking:*

So I saw in an app someone calculating an agreement rate after a round of votes between options. I am looking to do something similar. People will choose among a few options, and for each round I would like to have a number expressing how much they are agreeing in that vote. We are picking numbers, and I will show them an average of those numbers. People the more people vote for the same number, the higher I expect this "agreement" rating to be. So if everyone votes for the same thing, the agreement would be 100. If nobody votes for the same thing, I would think it would be 0. But then maybe the ones that chose similar options (lets say 1 and 2 are similar, but 8 and 1 are not), so I would expect that agreement to be higher if more people choose similar numbers (1s and 2s) than if people picked 1s and 8s.
I posted this question here because I thought 'statistics' would have some similar concept that I am not familiar with.

Comment: Some information seems to be missing. Does each voter only vote once? What is a "voting round"?

Comment: thank you, @cdalitz, I have edited my question to provide more details

Comment: What *is* 'voting agreement'? Do you refer to some well defined term or is is something vague and you are looking for input about how to define it?

Comment: The difficulty we face is that we know *too many* ways to assess "agreement" and we recognize the choice, to be a decent one, ought to depend on your context, data, and objectives.  Asking only for a "nice way" is just too broad.  If you want a simple, understandable way, why not report exactly the quantity you mention: percentage of pairs of identical votes relative to all possible pairs?  If that's not suitable, then please tell us and explain why not.  That can give us useful information for suggesting methods that will be more suitable.